# Unable to cast from object array to a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, object, casting

### This is my function.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ArrayToDictionaryConverter(object [] objArray)
    {
        string[] strArray = new string[objArray.Length];
        strArray =(string[])objArray;
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = null;
        try
        {
            dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int iVal = 0; iVal < strArray.Length; )
            {
                dictionary.Add(strArray[iVal], strArray[iVal + 1]);
                iVal += 2;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

---

Getting error :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String[]'.
```

Why ? is this wrong convention / Casting?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016654/classcastexception-when-casting-object-array-to-long-array for the correct answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Array.ConvertAll` method.

Answer (score 6):

You can't cast an expression to a particular type if it's not actually *of* that type, or a compatible one (or there's an explicit conversion).

In this case, the array wasn't a `string[]` - it was an `object[]`. It *could* have been a `string[]`, which is why the compiler allowed you to write the cast in the first place - but at execution time the CLR found that it was just an `object[]`.

Do you expect every element in the array to already *be* a string? If so, you should just cast each element individually. If not, you'll have to add a call to `ToString` (or some other way of converting each element to a string) - but be careful of null values.

As an aside, empty catch blocks are a *really* bad idea. What do you *really* want to happen if something goes wrong? And what kind of errors do you want to handle in what way? Some errors to think about:

- What if one of the keys is null?
- What if you get duplicate keys?
- What if the input array has an odd number of elements?

Finally, I'd suggest putting the `i += 2` in the for loop "header" instead of at the end of the block.

Comment: +1: This is my favorite question during an interview. People usually get confused between CONVERT and CAST

Answer (score -1):

See This is working:
public Dictionary ArrayToDictionaryConverter(object [] objArray)
        {
            string[] strArray = Array.ConvertAll(objArray,Convert.ToString);
            Dictionary dictionary = null;
            try
            {
                dictionary = new Dictionary();
                for (int iVal = 0; iVal < strArray.Length; )
                {
                    dictionary.Add(strArray[iVal], strArray[iVal + 1]);
                    iVal += 2;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return dictionary;
        }

Comment: -1 for using Convert.ToString when there's no such package Convert